# JPQL JOIN FETCH multiple tables also with empty collections

Tags: jpa, join, eclipselink, jpql

I am simply trying to get a whole entity with all attributes including empty collections, if they are empty.

```
public class Users extends BaseEntity {

    ...

    @Column(name = "Prename")
    private String prename;

    @Column(name = "session")
    private String session;

    @JsonView({ View.Users.class })
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
        name="USERS_PROJECTS",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="USERS_ID", referencedColumnName="id")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="PROJECT_ID", referencedColumnName="id")})
    private Set<Project> projects = new HashSet<>();

    @JsonView({ View.Users.class })
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "projectManager",
                cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE },
                fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Project> managingProjects = new HashSet<>();

    @JsonView({ View.Users.class })
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "projectManager",
                cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE },
                fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Project> watchingProjects = new HashSet<>();

    ...
}
```

The corresponding named query looks like this:

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
            name = Users.QUERY_GET_ALL_USERS_ASC,
            query = "SELECT u " +
                    "FROM Users u " +
                    "LEFT JOIN FETCH u.projects proj " +
                    "LEFT JOIN FETCH u.managingProjects manProj " +
                    "LEFT JOIN FETCH u.watchingProjects watProj " +
                    "ORDER BY u.email ASC")
})
```

This query returns about 350 objects whereas it should return only 17, probably because it is not "GROUPED".

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
            name = Users.QUERY_GET_ALL_USERS_ASC,
            query = "SELECT u " +
                    "FROM Users u " +
                    "JOIN FETCH u.projects proj " +
                    "JOIN FETCH u.managingProjects manProj " +
                    "JOIN FETCH u.watchingProjects watProj " +
                    "ORDER BY u.email ASC")
})
```

This query returns 0 objects, because not every object relates to a not empty watchingProjects or managingProjects collection.

```
@NamedQuery(
        name = Users.QUERY_GET_ALL_USERS_ASC,
        query = "SELECT u " +
                "FROM Users u " +
                "LEFT JOIN FETCH u.projects proj " +
                "LEFT JOIN FETCH u.managingProjects manProj " +
                "LEFT JOIN FETCH u.watchingProjects watProj " +
                "GROUP BY u " // + ", manProj, watProj " + // does not change anything
                "ORDER BY u.email ASC")
```

This query evokes the following exception:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "t1.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
  Position: 99
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT t0.ID, t0.CreateDate, t0.EMail, t0.Lastname, t0.Password, t0.Prename, t0.Role, t0.session, t1.ID, t1.Name, t1.Scheme, t2.ID, t2.Name, t2.Scheme, t3.ID, t3.Name, t3.Scheme FROM Users t0 LEFT OUTER JOIN (USERS_PROJECTS t6 JOIN PROJECT t1 ON (t1.ID = t6.PROJECT_ID)) ON (t6.USERS_ID = t0.ID) LEFT OUTER JOIN (PROJECTS_MANAGER t7 JOIN PROJECT t2 ON (t2.ID = t7.PROJECT_ID)) ON (t7.MANAGER_ID = t0.ID) LEFT OUTER JOIN (PROJECTS_MANAGER t8 JOIN PROJECT t3 ON (t3.ID = t8.PROJECT_ID)) ON (t8.MANAGER_ID = t0.ID) LEFT OUTER JOIN (PROJECTS_MANAGER t9 JOIN PROJECT t4 ON (t4.ID = t9.PROJECT_ID)) ON (t9.MANAGER_ID = t0.ID) LEFT OUTER JOIN (PROJECTS_MANAGER t10 JOIN PROJECT t5 ON (t5.ID = t10.PROJECT_ID)) ON (t10.MANAGER_ID = t0.ID) GROUP BY t0.ID, t0.CreateDate, t0.EMail, t0.Lastname, t0.Password, t0.Prename, t0.Role, t0.session, t4.ID, t4.Name, t4.Scheme, t5.ID, t5.Name, t5.Scheme ORDER BY t0.EMail ASC
```

Setting the FetchType to LAZY is not an option, because there are other queries which should not fetch these attributes. So the question is how is it possible to return all the entities with a JPQL query with possible empty collections?
I am using EclipseLink 2.6.2 and JPA 2.1.

Comment: How many objects are returned if you use `SELECT u FROM Users u`? I think you need to use 'DISTINCT'. i.e. `SELECT distinct u FROM Users u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.projects proj ...`.

Comment: This is why the specification section dealing with "queries with relationsihips" uses examples with the DISTINCT key word.  Joins over collections return a row for each element in the collection, and JPA's results mirror the SQL results you are requesting, even though the results may not be included explicitly in the select.

Comment: Thank you very much! 'DISTINCT' was indeed the solution!

Comment: @Priyesh As your solution works for Rooky, you should have to post your solutions as answer. So, Rooky can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

How many objects are returned if you use SELECT u FROM Users u? I think you need to use 'DISTINCT'. i.e.

```
SELECT distinct u FROM Users u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.projects proj ...
```